# Meta Data File in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have just started learning unity and was just building a simple game but today when I just changed some code in a script. Unity started giving me this errors

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.9.1.65535 (9d34608e)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

error CS0009: Metadata file 'C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.14f1\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine\UnityEngine.ParticleSystemModule.dll' could not be opened -- Invalid assembly name: ''
```

I don't know what is this I restarted Unity and nothing happened

Here is My File Hierarchy:

```
    Unity_Projects
         My First Game
               .vscode
                   settings.json
               Assets
                 Scenes
                    Nothing
                 FollowPlayer.cs
                 PlayerColiison.cs
                 PlayerMovement.cs
                 Slippery.physicMaterial
              Logs
                Packages-Update.log
              Packages
                manifest.json
                packages-lock.json
              Assembly-CSharp.csproj
              My First Game.sln
```

I don't know that what is happening and I use VsCode because Visual Studio hangs my Machine
If Anyone know this please tell me how to fix it

Thanks For Helping!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give us more specific details regarding your question. Here are some scenarios:

1. What did you change since the code was running?
2. Did you move anything from the Unity folder or your project folder?
3. Are you using a different setup from your initial project setup?
4. Did you downgrade the project?

Also, regarding the text editor,
make sure to configure your code editor settings correctly by going to Unity -> Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools and select your code editor. I strongly recommend you use Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition instead of VS Code, since Visual Studio has a lot of built-in features for Unity.